# Backpropagation calculation: why this order and an element-wise multiplication?

Tags: deep-learning, backpropagation

I am reading the [Direct Feedback Alignment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01596) paper, and I don't understand why in the Formula (6) on page 3 in the backpropagation calculation, he used element-wise multiplication and why the order is such. I did my own calculation.

What he got:

da_1 = (W_2^T da_2) ⊙ f'(a_1)

What I got:

da_1 = da_2 f'(a_1) W_2

I kinda get it that I need to change something for matrix multiplication to happen, is it the reason?